# Laravel Migration: "ERROR Class not found"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

I'm new to Laravel, I'm building a small project with five tables: users, products, category, transactions, and a pivot table category_product. When I try to run the command
`Php artisan migrate`
I receive an error **class "Transaction" not found**

here are the tables.

**User Table**

[image]

**Reset Password Table**

[image]

**Products Table**

[image]

**Categories Table**

[image]

**Transactions Table**

[image]

**Category_product Table**

[image]

** The order of Migrations in the Migration Folder**

[image]

**And here is the full error I received**

[image]

Comment: please share a picture of migrations folder because the order of your migration files are also important.

Comment: added the solution, check it now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

laravel get the migration class name from migration file name, to solve this:

1- rename file `2020_11_06_transactions`  to `2020_11_06_create_transactions_table`

2-`composer dumpautoload`

3-`php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: This is really a useful info, `_create_` define the class name from migration files

Answer (score 1):

1. at first change the file name of transactions from `2020_11_06_200236_transactions.php` to `2020_11_06_200236_create_transactions_table.php`
2. run the command to refresh your migrations which you runned previously:

```
   php artisan migrate:refresh
```